# Restart Windows 10 every 30 days in Kiosk Mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, kiosk, uwp

Is there a way to schedule a restart every month of the kiosk mode (Meaning the PC)?
I know how I can do it on my account in home, but not sure if that is possible in that mode?

Answer (score 1):

Kiosk mode only affects the user interface. Windows itself works as usual,
so you may create a task to restart by using the Task Scheduler.

Use a batch (`.bat`) script that uses the
[shutdown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)
like this:

```
shutdown /r
```